# database design - categories and sub-categories

Tags: sql, database

I need to implement Categorization and Sub-Categorization on something which is a bit similar to golden pages.

Assume I have the following table:

## Category Table

```
CategoryId, Title
10, Home
20, Business
30, Hobbies
```

I have two options to code the sub-categorization.

## OPTION 1 - Subcategory Id is unique within Category ONLY:

## Sub Category Table

```
CategoryId, SubCategoryId, Title
10, 100, Gardening
10, 110, Kitchen
10, 120, ...
20, 100, Development
20, 110, Marketing
20, 120, ...
30, 100, Soccer
30, 110, Reading
30, 120, ...
```

## OPTION 2 - Subcategory Id is unique OVERALL:

## Sub Category Table

```
CategoryId, SubCategoryId, Title
10, 100, Gardening
10, 110, Kitchen
10, 120, ...
20, 130, Development
20, 140, Marketing
20, 150, ...
30, 160, Soccer
30, 170, Reading
30, 180, ...
```

Option 2 sounds like it is easier to fetch rows from table
For example: `SELECT BizTitle FROM tblBiz WHERE SubCatId = 170`

whereas using Option 1 I'd have to write something like this:

```
SELECT BizTitle FROM tblBiz WHERE CatId = 30 AND SubCatId = 170
```

i.e., containing an extra `AND`

However, Option 1 is easier to maintain manually (when I need to update and insert new subcategories etc. and it is more pleasant to the eye in my opinion.

Any thoughts about it? Does Option 2 worth the trouble in terms of efficiency? Is there any design patters related with this common issue?

Comment: i think you have to go with option 2 make one table for Category where categoryid is PK and make another table SubCategory where subcategoryid is PK and categoryid is FK

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would use this structure:

```
ParentId, CategoryId, Title
null, 1, Home
null, 2, Business
null, 3, Hobbies
1, 4, Gardening
1, 5, Kitchen
1, 6, ...
2, 7, Development
2, 8, Marketing
2, 9, ...
3, 10, Soccer
3, 11, Reading
3, 12, ...
```

In detail:

- only use one table, which **references itself**, so that you can have unlimited depth of categories
- use **technical ids** (using `IDENTITY`, or similar), so that you can have more than 10 subcategories
- if required add a **human readable** column for category-numbers as **separate field**

As long as you are only using two levels of categories you can still select like this:

```
SELECT BizTitle FROM tblBiz WHERE ParentId = 3 AND CategoryId = 11
```

---

The new `hierarchyid` feature of SQL server also looks quite promising: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx

---

What I don't like about the **Nested Set Model**:

- **Inserting and deleting** items in the *Nested Set Model* is a quite comlicated thing and requires expensive locks.
- One can easily create **inconsistencies** which is prohibited, if you use the `parent` field in combination with a foreign key constraint.

  - Inconsistencies can appear, if `rght` is **lower** than `lft`
  - Inconsistencies can appear, if a value **apprears in several** `rght` or `lft` fields
  - Inconsistencies can appear, if you create **gaps**
  - Inconsistencies can appear, if you create **overlaps**
- The *Nested Set Model* is in my opinion more *complex* and therefore not as easy to understand. This is absolutely subjective, of course.
- The *Nested Set Model* requires two fields, instead of one - and so uses more disk space.

Comment: in that case each time we have to apply self join to get our category with subcategory is it feasible way

Comment: @tinka If you are only using two levels of depth you can still make easy selects (see my update)

Comment: I couldn't make up my mind firmly. But I took your suggestion. Thanks for all you guys trying to help.

Comment: You really should get to know nested sets model. This answer is not always the best way to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: @paulus I don't like the *Nested Set Model* and added the drawbacks of that model to my answer.

Comment: @slartidan indeed in the end of a day it is a matter of personal preferences.

Comment: Refer to this article https://explainextended.com/2009/09/24/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-postgresql/ which gives a good comparison between the adjacency list and nested sets models and provides sample queries to find ancestors and descendants.

Answer (score 19):

Managing hierarchical data has some ways. One of the most important ones is `Nested Set Model`. [See here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) for implementation. Even some content management systems like Joomla, use this structure.

**Update 2020:** As there are some considerations on this post, I should say that now I prefer the Adjacency List Model instead of the Nested Set Model since there is less complexity in this way. Also [See here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adjacency-list-tree/) for implementation.

Comment: 2020 solution is simple and clear. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend going with **option 1** - keep sub-category unique within category. Let's say I have two categories of unrelated items:

- Fruits
- Colors

For each I want a subcategory

- Fruits

  - Apple
  - Orange
- Colors

  - White
  - Orange

Notice that Orange is a sub-category within each category. Although the name is the same, it's function is very different. (Let's not get into the possibility that Orange fruit is orange in color)

With this design, if someone changes their mind and wants to rename Orange to Oranges, fine. It's easy to change without affecting Orange sub-category under Colors.

If your UI is built in such a way that Marketing can control subcategories of Colors whereas Production can control subcategories of Fruits, this design will allow Marketing to work with their subcategories without stepping over Production's subcategories.