# EF Code First access child of child to set ForeignKey

Tags: ef-code-first, ef-code-first-mapping

Below are the sample classes

```
public class Parent {
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public Child Child{get; set;}
}

public class Child {
    public Child1[] ListChild1 {get; set;}
}

public class Child1 {
    public int Child1Id {get; set;}
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public int Child1Name {get;set;}
}
```

Need to create the table using Entity Framework Code-First approach. ParentId is PK in Parent and FK in Child1. No need to create 
table for Child class. Child1 table has Child1Id as PK and ParentId as FK. Need some help how to create this relationship in database
using fluent api.
Required Databse structure
Parent
ParentId (PK)
UserName

Child1
Child1Id (PK)
ParentId (FK)
ChildName

Answer (score 0):

I have used something similar in the past :

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

This should work for an infinite parent, children relationship in the same table.

Comment: This looks like a self referencing. Is this a class structure for class Child1 in the above example?

Comment: My Approach is , instead of creating two tables , you only create one since(I am assuming ) the parent and the children are from the same type.
 
Take a look at this   https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623630/2108385